# How do I sort a taxonomy in a different way depending on the language?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a taxonomy (list of hobbies) translated using Entity Translation.

The list is in alphabetical order, which is great for English.

However, I also translated the list into Japanese, which uses a completely different order from English.  Unfortunately, within Drupal this list is shown in the same order as the English list.

I need to show this list to both Japanese and English speakers and have the terms linked so using two separate lists is not an option.

How can I sort a taxonomy list differently based on the language?  Is it possible to have a solution such as different weights for different languages?